# Error converting strings to float in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I scraped some financial data from a site, and stored it in a Pandas Dataframe. The numbers are stored as strings, which I tried to convert to floats via the usual `df['Col Name'].astype(float)` command, but ran into an error due to the presence of a `-` (a dash) in the original website. The error message is `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'`.

My intention is to make calculations using the values in the different columns, so this is an obvious roadblock. 
I also considered replacing the `-` with `0`, but then again, that would cause other errors due to division by 0.

What could be a few possible options to solve this?

```
Example of the dataframe value:
|      | P/B   | P/E    | PEG  |   |
|------|-------|--------|------|---|
| AMZN | 18.89 | 102.68 | 3.17 |   |
| GOOG | 4.32  | -      | 1.62 |   |
| IBM  | -     | 11.12  | 3.35 |   |
```

Comment: `df['Col Name'].replace('-','0').astype(float)`?

Comment: you could probably just use .strip to get rid of the '-' can you edit your question to have some examples of the strings?

Answer (score 0):

You could make those dashes NaN.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'inds':['AMZN', 'GOOG', 'IBM'],
                   'P/B':[18.89, 4.32, '-'], 
                   'P/E':[102.68, '-', 11.12], 
                   'PEG':[3.17, 1.62, 3.35]})
df.set_index('inds', inplace=True)
df.index.name = None
df

|      | P/B   | P/E    | PEG  |   |
|------|-------|--------|------|---|
| AMZN | 18.89 | 102.68 | 3.17 |   |
| GOOG | 4.32  | -      | 1.62 |   |
| IBM  | -     | 11.12  | 3.35 |   |
```

Then you can replace the dashes (and any other char, just put it in the square brackets) with

```
df = df.replace('[-]', np.nan, regex=True)
```

which is

```
df
|      | P/B   | P/E    | PEG  |   |
|------|-------|--------|------|---|
| AMZN | 18.89 | 102.68 | 3.17 |   |
| GOOG | 4.32  | NaN    | 1.62 |   |
| IBM  | NaN   | 11.12  | 3.35 |   |
```

so you can divide things and NaN values then

```
df['P/B'] / df['P/E']
AMZN    0.18397
GOOG        NaN
IBM         NaN
dtype: float64
```

Beyond that, you're just going to have to determine the appropriate strategy for imputing values for the analysis you want to do.